# How to use rdfdistiller via curl

Tags: rdfa

I am trying to use the [rdf distiller by Gregg Kollegg](https://github.com/gkellogg/rdf-distiller):

which works nicely via the web ui:

http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/distiller?command=serialize&url=http:%2F%2Fceur-ws.org%2FVol-2549%2F

now i'd like to get the result via curl and kind find an example/documentation for it.
I have also filed an issue for this at:
https://github.com/gkellogg/rdf-distiller/issues/35

**How would the curl command look like to get one of the offered triple formats?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in the Ruby RDF Distiller. It's been a useful tool for many years, and has grown to allow access to more formats and functionality from the various Linked Data Ruby gems.

I provided an answer on the [Github Issue](https://github.com/gkellogg/rdf-distiller/issues/35#issuecomment-1218325216). If you're using the web interface, as you selection options from the UI, it will update the URL in the "Alternative access to the Distiller" section. To get "raw" output, that bypasses the HTML text box, use the "raw" option, although this seems to work better using "curl".

Also noted in the issue response, is that the entire Distiller service is powered using the "rdf" CLI, which is installed when you install the "rdf" or "linkeddata" ruby gems. (The "linkeddata" gem depends on all of the various gems in the Ruby RDF ecosystem, so provides the fullest functionality).

PRs against the repo to improve documentation or functionality are welcome.